# How to replace text with image(is it possible in flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

```
var replaced = text.replaceAll(regExp, '*');
```

Instead of the asterisk mark can we replace this with actual image..

Comment: How you want to replace the image I didn't get it? As I know you can or you are willing to change the path or the image that's what is possible. please describe your question

Comment: i have saved bunch of emojis as images locally i want replace a specific text on the message as this image emoji.

Comment: you don't need images for emojis you can use emoji unicodes

Comment: yeah but i was specifically told to do it in this way is there any luck..

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So you have bunch of emojis stored locally. and you have to replace a text with emoji.

I don't have a perfect answer. but how you can achieve a path that i can show.
Using a map. as you are suppose to change the text for an image there must be a pair. so you can define a map for it. a key will be a text and the value will be the path of the emoji. considering your folder as a `images` and format is `png`.

```
   Map<String, String> myData = {"like" : "images/like.png", "time": 
    "images/time.png"};
```

and so on. Like this you can create a full map of it. if it's limited like 30 -40 records that you will do manually.

Now you can perform operations on that. Suppose you have String value = " I like your shirt!";
so we need to scan the string and then search every word inside tha map and replace if you found it.
the code looks like this

```
void main() {
  //your value that you are going to scan
   String str = " I like your shirt";

 //Defining the map
    Map<String, String> data = {"like" : "images/like.png", "shirt" : 
    "images/shirt.png", "happy" : "images/happy.png"};


  //function that will do the changes and display 

  void replaceTextWithEmojis(String value, Map<String, String> data){

  
  //splitting the value into the array or list of items so we can iterate easily
  List<String> inputvalues = str.split(" ");
     //looping through the text
    for (int i =0; i<inputvalues.length; i++){
  
  //checking where that text is present in the emojis map or not.
  if(data.containsKey(inputvalues[i])){
  
  //this will replace the text with the path for that key
  inputvalues[i] = data[inputvalues[i]];
  }
} //end of the for loop
print(inputvalues);
}


replaceTextWithEmojis(str, data);
 }
```

This will replace with the desired values. But You want to display a image between the text. That's what something difficult. I don't think you can do it in flutter. Or it will be like you need to identify the position of the replaceable text and then break the string and store it in other variable. append the image at the breakpoint. so at the place where we are replacing with the map you can add a `widget(child ImageProvider(inputvalue[i]));`

I would suggest you to use unicode for emojis.
you can use the package for unicode emjois : https://pub.dev/packages/emojis

Also they will give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Replace an emoticon or any string token with an image having a tooltip and Help cursor.
static List<Widget> replaceEmoji(final String text, final String fromToken, final String toImgTooltip, final String toImg) {

  Widget _getImage(final String path, final String tooltip) => MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.help,
        child: Tooltip(message: tooltip, child: Image.asset(path)),
      );

  if (!text.contains(fromToken)) {
    return [Text(text)];
  }
  final result = <Widget>[];
  var buffer = text;
  var n = -1;
  while (true) {
    n = buffer.indexOf(fromToken);
    if (n != 0) {
      result.add(Text(buffer.substring(0, n)));
    }
    result.add(_getImage(toImg, toImgTooltip));
    buffer = buffer.substring(n + fromToken.length);
    if (buffer.isEmpty) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You use it as follows:

```
...
Wrap(
  children: replaceEmoji('my :) face - :):)', ':)', 'smile', 'assets/images/emoji/smile.png')
)
...
```